MS-MPI and MPI4PY don't work on a real PC cluster
My LAN is composed of 1 PC Windows 10 Pro (manager) and 3 PCs Windows 11 Pro (workers). I installed on the PCs (manager and workers) MSMPI Microsoft MPI Startup Program Version 10.1.12498.52, MPI4PY v.3.1.5 and Python 3.11.5.  The following simple code “mpitest.py”  works fine on each PC in localhost modality:
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

print("I am the process ",rank)

and the command:
mpiexec python mpitest.py

but when I try to use all the PC cluster, it doesn’t work. The file mpitest.py is present in all 4 PCs in the C:\ folder. Only in the PC manager there is the file hosts.txt (also in C:/) containing the addresses of PC workers as follows (I omit the first 3 numbers for privacy reasons):
xxx.xxx.xxx.1
xxx.xxx.xxx.2
xxx.xxx.xxx.3

To start the process on the cluster I write the command:
mpiexec -machinefile hosts.txt python mpitest.py

Ping from the PC manager to the workers is active and works fine.
I also disabled firewalls and other protections.
I expected a list of messages "I am the process ... I am the process ..." coming from each worker and manager.
No error is generated, but it seems that the master is waiting for something.
What am I doing wrong?

SOLVED!
Run spmd -d on all computers node.
spmd.exe is available in the MPI folder after installation.
